# Managing storage for Virtual Machines in Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization (RHEV)

Tags: redhat, storage, rhev

I am using RHEV and I have created two virtual machines. These have too little disk space, how can I edit the disk space of these machines? I cannot find the option anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried? have you read our FAQ, it describes what we expect of question askers.

Comment: I understand your point, but my case is that I haven't been able to try anything because I haven't found a place where to try. I expected to find something like a "slider" on VM settings where storage could be resized when VM is offline, but I couldn't find. I also searched on RHEV documentation but could not find this. That is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the VM disk sizes in the current version of RHEV, uless you're using direct attached disks.
What you can do instead, is add an additional disk to the VM and stretch the available space over to it using LVM

Or you could just create a larger disk, attach it to the VM and `dd` the contents over

Answer (score 0):

The Red Hat docuemntation explains [how to use `virt-resize` to shrink or expand a guest disk image](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-virt-resize.html). If you haven't already read Red Hat's excellent documentation, you should do so now.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, RHEV 3.3 allows you to do this but it requires a reboot for the guest to pickup the block device size change.